# ansible is not able to find the yaml module

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I have installed ansible on ubuntu 20.04 using apt.

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /home/XXX/git/XXX/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/XX/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) [GCC 9.4.0]
```

When I try to use the helm

```
  - name: install helm chart
    kubernetes.core.helm:
      name: helm
      create_namespace: true
      namespace: abl
      chart_ref: ../my-chars
      values_files: helm-values.yaml
    tags: 
      - installHelm
```

I get the following message

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (yaml) on debian's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

I have installed pyYAML like this

```
pip3 install PyYAML
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (6.0)
```

everything seems ok, but ansible still complains

```
python3 -m pip freeze | grep YAML
PyYAML==6.0
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Please help :)

Comment: Where are you running that command: `python3 -m pip freeze | grep YAML`? Controller or nodes?

Comment: `python3 -m pip show PyYAML` is more appropriate to show what's going on with this requirement, BTW.

Comment: on the host - I want to be able to install helm charts from my host to the target

Comment: output of show ```python3 -m pip show PyYAML
Name: PyYAML
Version: 6.0
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://pyyaml.org/
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: /home/ikostov/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: kubernetes
```

Comment: upgrading to the latest ppa ansible - ansible [core 2.12.4] did not helped either :(

Comment: creating extra environment also did not helped ```  virtualenv py3-ansible  &&  source py3-ansible/bin/activate &&  pip3 install ansible ```

Answer (score 0):

the default behavior of kuberentes.core is to execute helm on the remote host. My expectation was that helm will be called locally. Default behavior can be changed by **delegate_to**

```
  - name: install helm chart
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    kubernetes.core.helm:
      name: helm
      create_namespace: true
      namespace: foo
      chart_ref: ../my-chars
      values_files: helm-values.yaml
    tags: 
      - installHelm
```